# How to format a string by altering case with spaces with C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to solve a problem based on Altering Case but there is a bit issue with that.
Assume the given string is:

```
"What is your name?"
```

I want to get the output:

```
"WhAt Is YoUr NaMe?"
```

After writing this code

```
    string str = "What is your name?";
    string[] strSplit = str.Split(' ');
    string strNoSpace = string.Empty;
    string newStr = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < strSplit.Length; i++)
    {
        strNoSpace += strSplit[i];
        
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < strNoSpace.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            newStr += char.ToUpper(strNoSpace[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            newStr += char.ToLower(strNoSpace[i]);
        }
        
    }
    Console.WriteLine(newStr);
```

I am getting this:

```
"WhAtIsYoUrNaMe?"
```

If I put space, the result is different:

```
"WhAt iS YoUr nAmA?"
```

It would be very kind if anyone help me to figure out what I am doing wrong in the code.

Comment: I suggest that you treat each word as an element of an array and apply your algorithm to each of those elements individually. Then, when you reconstruct the sentence, you add the spaces to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert the string into a `StringBuilder`. Unlike a `string`, a `StringBuilder` is mutable and allows each character to be changed. Also, I would not split the string into words, but instead only invert the case when the character is a letter:

```cs
string str = "What is your name?";
bool toUpper = true;

var sb = new StringBuilder(str);
for (int i = 0; i < sb.Length; i++) {
    if (Char.IsLetter(sb[i])) { 
        if (toUpper) {
            sb[i] = Char.ToUpper(sb[i]);
        } else {
            sb[i] = Char.ToLower(sb[i]);
        }
        toUpper = !toUpper; // Invert the case
    }
}
str = sb.ToString();
```

The test `Char.IsLetter` excludes white spaces, digits, and punctuation.

Note that this code uses the Boolean flag `toUpper` instead of relying on the index's divisibility by two which gives a wrong information after a space.

Comment: I like the more procedural way actually, but this answer helps me to understand, solving using StringBuilder Object and storing the string in a more dynamic way. Also, I liked your explanation of the perspective of my question.

Answer (score 0):

You're very close! You just need to insert the spaces back into the sentence when you combine it again.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < strNoSpace.Length; i++)
{
      if (i % 2 == 0)
      {
          newStr += char.ToUpper(strNoSpace[i]);
      }
      else
      {
          newStr += char.ToLower(strNoSpace[i]);
      }
      newStr += ' '; // <--- this line
}

// And then trim the remaining whitespace
Console.WriteLine(newStr.Trim());
```

Comment: I have tried this one earlier, in that every character is spaced like `"W h A t I s Y o U r N a M e ?"`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you explicitly remove all the spaces from the string, and your indexing does not take spaces into account. I would suggest something like this instead:

```
        bool odd = false;
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var c in str)
        {
            if (char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
            {
                sb.Append(c);
                continue;
            }

            sb.Append(odd ? char.ToLower(c) : char.ToUpper(c));
            odd = !odd;
        }
```

This keeps a separate state if the character should be lower or upper, and skips spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
        string str = "What is your name?";
        var arr = str.ToCharArray();
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == ' ')
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (k % 2 == 0)
                arr[i] = char.ToUpper(arr[i]);
            else
                arr[i] = char.ToLower(arr[i]);
            k++;
        }
        string newStr = new string(arr);
```

Out put is:

```
WhAt Is YoUr NaMe?
```

Comment: The answer is more acceptable, classic, and using a simple method that I more like.